# Airy-type integrals (with different power $\neq 3$)

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, special-functions, bessel-functions

I am looking for integrals closely related to the Airy function

\begin{eqnarray} &&
A_1=  \int _0^\infty x \sin \Phi dx
\nonumber \\ &&
A_2= \int _0^\infty  \cos \Phi dx
\nonumber \\&&
\Phi =\xi x (1+c_1 x^\kappa)
\end{eqnarray}

For $\kappa=2$ this is Airy function/Bessel's $K_{1/3}$. What about $\kappa \neq 2$?

I think it would involve $K_{1/(1+\kappa)} (\xi)$.

Comment: These's some information about a family including $A_2$ under "canonical integrals" here https://dlmf.nist.gov/36.2

Comment: for $\kappa=1$ it's a combination of Fresnel integrals, I don't see a $K_{1/2}$ emerge...

Comment: @CarloBeenakker, true, kappa=1 seems a border-line case. I need kappa > 1.

Comment: Hardy and Littlewood integrals come up, but seems no simple analytical formula.